# apache2 is using different directory than what it should be

Tags: apache2, html

I have a default Debian installation of Apache2, but when I attempted to change the file at `/var/www/html/index.html`, nothing happened, because for some reason apache is using the file at `/usr/share/apache2/default-site/index.html` instead.

How do I make apache use the files at `/var/www/html` ?

Thank you!

EDIT: Turns out, apache was working properly. I just didn't realize that I logged out of my server, and was actually editing my local machine's files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access other folder then /var/www/html in Apache2 over http](http://askubuntu.com/questions/611261/access-other-folder-then-var-www-html-in-apache2-over-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the location in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file.  You will have to edit the file as `sudo` since it is owned by root.

Make sure the following line looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

Restart apache2

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: My file already looks like that, and restarting apache did not work.

Comment: @WestonReed Silly question, but did you Reload the page so it is not pulling from a cached page?

Comment: Ok, so I really feel like an idiot right now. Turns out I forgot that I logged out of my server, and was editing my local machine's files, so of course it wasn't updating. I'm sorry!

Comment: @WestonReed No problem!  Glad you got it fixed!  :)

Comment: @WestonReed It is never a waste of time.  I'm very happy to help!  =)